# Why does the distribution of p-values peak at around zero when running a 1000x bootstrapped t-test on my data?

Tags: r, p-value, statistics-bootstrap

I have some numerical measurements on two groups of people and I would like to compare means between these two groups. Just using a t-test for that purpose which gives me a confidence interval and p-value. Now, I'd like do a bootstrap analysis on this data to get a feel for the variability of both the CI and p-values.

I'm using R and the `boot` package. The data is stored in dataframe `data`. To calculate the statistics I have this function:

```
calculate <- function(formula, data, indices) {
    d <- data[indices,]
    m <- t.test(formula, data=d)
    return(c(m$conf.int, m$p.value))
}
```

Then I run the bootstrap as follows:

```
results <- boot(data=data, statistic=calculate, R=1000, formula=y ~ x)
```

Then I plot the p-values in "results" as follows:

```
hist(results$t[,3], breaks=32)
```

The histogram looks as shown below. I understand that the distribution of p-values is skewed because the p-value is constrained to be no smaller than zero. But I don't understand why the peak of the distribution is at zero as well, no matter how many breaks I display in the histogram.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!
[image: Histogram of bootstrapped p-value distribution]

Comment: From the topic tag - "R is a free software environment for statistical computing and graphics. This tag can be used for questions about running R software on macOS. Questions about programming in R should be asked on StackOverflow."

Comment: Actually this probably should have been migrated to [stats.se]. Or at the very least include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) here so we can run it to see what's going on. Otherwise Cross Validated can help with a more theoretical statistical answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's not a question about R or MacOS but about data.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks, I will repost the question in CV and try and provide an example that can be reproduced

Comment: i think you are confusing bootstrap with permutation. if the original observation has a low pvalue, meaning there are indications of difference between groups, when you bootstrap you should something like this, because the difference is large enough for most of the bootstraps

Comment: when you bootstrap, you simply resample your data.. so if the majority of your observations do agree with this difference, this is what you expect

Answer (score 0):

We can try with an example dataset:

```
library(boot)
set.seed(111)
data = data.frame(y = rnorm(60,rep(0:1,each=30),1),x=rep(1:2,each=30))

results <- boot(data=data, statistic=calculate, R=1000, formula=y ~ x)
```

The original observation itself is significant:

```
t.test(y~x,data=data)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  y by x
t = -4.0621, df = 55.339, p-value = 0.0001547
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.8262396 -0.6197054
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
     -0.1881403       1.0348322
```

And even if you sample it you, most of the bootstraps will show a significant value, but we can see how this varies on the -log10 scale, actual observed value in blue:

```
hist(-log10(results$t[,3]),br=20,xlab="Bootstrap -log 10 p values")
abline(v= -log10(results$t0[3]),lty=8,col="blue")
```

[image]